# ORDS authentication: username and password possible?

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, iis-10, oracle-ords

I'm using Oracle Rest Data Services (ORDS) to build APIs.

The client requires basic authentication (username and password). This does not seem to be supported by OAUTH2.

Is there another way I can protect the APIs by means of just a username and password?

**EDIT:**
We are using IIS10 - is it possible to setup basic authentication from an IIS perspective?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but we don't recommend it.

You can create an ORDS user (use the user command), and assign a password and one or more roles.

You can fall back to database user/password auth. That authenticated user session is given a role called 'SQL Developer,' so if your REST API was protected via  privilege that was also put into the 'SQL Developer' role, it would get authorized.

We don't recommend this for a few reasons.

One of the biggest is [how much slower it is](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/10/working-with-dates-in-ords-and-a-reminder-to-use-oauth2/). We have to make an actual database connection to ensure your user/password combo are correct. That takes TIME.

Hence, we point folks to OAuth2, or something higher up the stack like an API Gateway.

Coming later this year, we'll have out-of-the-box support for OpenID. This will add tremendous amounts of flexibility without sacrificing security or performance.

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am a product manager for ORDS.*

Comment: Thank you @thatjeffsmith. Do you have an tutorial to to this? Our client uses a third party tool which does not support tokens, only username/password

Comment: I managed to to basic authentication and call the procedure directly (as per this POC https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-database-authentication).
then I went further and defined a Module and Handler, but then I continue to get 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: You need to start a new question if you want help debugging your API and the 500 (hint: go look at the ords standard output logs to get the error stack behind the 500)